# Custom sorting compare in Ember

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a problem with sorting in Ember.

I use `moment.js` for handling all times in ember, I never use plain javascript date objects since I need to always be aware of timezone set by the user. When I do `array.sortBy('datetime')` and the properties for sorting are moment.js objects, sorting does not work, since compare method used by ember threat moment js as objects, thus returning 0. Is there any way to override default compare method as defined here - https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v1.13.0/packages/ember-runtime/lib/compare.js#L26.

Since the method is included in mixins as `Enumerable` and others as closure and cannot be overridden afterwards.

**Note**: I don't want to use custom sorting like `array.sort(function(a, b) ...`, I want to use `sortBy` and have compare function handle the logic behind the curtain.

Thanks in adance

Answer (score 0):

Simply override the `sortyBy` method and have it use your own compare function.

You can do the overriding in an Ember CLI initializer.

Comment: Yeah, but `compare` is used on lot of places - native Array, ArrayProxy, SortableMixin and so on... So you have to replace compare on all this places (that includes Enumerable mixin), since ember already included it and when you reopen Enumerable, it won't change on all places that includes that mixin.